# SharePoint Online - SharePoint-hosted Add-In REST API is getting a "403 (FORBIDDEN)/500 (Internal Error)"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to create a SharePoint-hosted Add-In for our SharePoint Online site. I'm using AngularJS as well to help with the front-end.

Using REST API, I have absolutely no trouble reading from a list. However, when I try to write onto that same list, I kept getting a 403.

Here is the code for my `WritePage.js` file:

```
app.controller('spListController', function ($scope, $http) {
console.log("In NewPage!");

this.startInsert = function () {
    var promise = this.insertItems($scope);
    promise.then(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    },
    function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Error:\n" + status);
    });
};

this.insertItems = function ($scope) {
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('My List')/items";
    var requestBody = JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.MyListListItem' },
        'Title': this.Title,
    });
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        body: requestBody,
        headers: {
            //"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken // <-- I keep seeing these in online examples. Is this what I need?
            //"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), // <-- Keeping this turns the 403 into a 500.
            "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Ensure that the user has write access to the SharePoint list by checking permission.

2) If above is true, then ensure that SP hosted add-in has permission to write data to list. Check the `appmanifest.xml` .

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting a `403` even with all those three in `FullControl`. I tried checking the `Allow the app to...` option and it makes no difference. (Yes, I've selected the list I want to give `Write` permissions to.)